# Anguraljs Custom directive does not work after changing the object declaration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have added custom `validation-summary` directive in my project [from this git-hub link.](https://github.com/sgudjonsson/angular-validation-summary/blob/master/validationSummary.js) It works fine.

```
angular.module("ValidationSummaryModule").directive("validationSummary", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "^form",
        template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='(expression,message) in validationMessages'>{{message}}</li></ul>",
        link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {

            scope.validationMessages = {};

            // Hooks up a watch using [ng-show] expression
            controller.watchValidation = function(expression, message) {

                // watch the return value from the scope.$eval(expression)
                scope.$watch(function() { return scope.$eval(expression); }, function(isVisible) {

                    // check if the validation message exists
                    var containsMessage = scope.validationMessages.hasOwnProperty(expression);

                    // if the validation message doesn't exist and it should be visible, add it to the list
                    if(!containsMessage && isVisible)
                        scope.validationMessages[expression] = message;

                    // if the validation message does exist and it shouldn't be visible, delete it
                    if(containsMessage && !isVisible)
                        delete scope.validationMessages[expression];
                });

            };

        }
    };
});
```

But if I change the object declaration from `scope.validationMessages = {};` to `scope.validationMessages = [];` It does not work. I debugged the code in browser but could not find out the reason.

I need to change the declaration because `scope.validationMessages = {};` give me an unordered list. I need ordered list.

Comment: how will (key,value) loop work on array? is will not of course

Comment: Have a look at [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Comment: @null orderBy what?? I do not want alphabetic order. For example for `First name` and `Last name` input fields, I want 'First name required' validation message first then 'Last name required' message. I meant this order.

Comment: @KhalidHussain: You can order it in any way you like -- just specify a function. From the documentation: _function: Getter function. The result of this function will be sorted using the <, ===, > operator._